# Technical advantages of Rasa framework compared to Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have been using Rasa for building bots with somewhat complex stories. I have even started using slightly modified custom training components in the pipeline.

However, I was requested to perform a detailed comparison of Rasa vs Dialogflow and I lack the time and experience to get myself quite familiar with DF. I know that Rasa + SDK allows extreme levels of customization, and I’ve become quite accustomed to it. My question to users of this forum in general who has experience with Dialogflow is whether there are any known technical limitations of Dialogflow compared to the Rasa stack? I’ve come across this https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-migrate-your-existing-google-dialogflow-assistant-to-rasa, but it lacks technical depth in the comparison. Apart from being closed sourced and data ownership issues, are there any fundamental limitations to Dialogflow that I can quote?

Basically, if you know how to break DF or you hate it for some reasons, please leave some comments.
(originally posted on Rasa Community forum, but felt that this question might be answered better by the general public)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I find DialogFlow having the following limitations:

- it is a cloud-service so all the conversations (and data) your chatbot originates will go via the Google cloud
- it has good NLP capabilities, but you have no control of it: unlike Rasa you cannot change the pipeline and models involved in the NLU phase
- the conversations are designed using the DialogFlow UI, which works fine, but doesnt allow (easily) to automate or integrate external apps for designing your flow
- the DialogFlow Web Chat plugin is very basic and is not suitable for Production usage (only for testing)
- if you develop a Webhook (any non-trivial chatbot needs one) you have to tunnel the DialogFlow requests to your local development env (laptop) so you need NGROK or another tunnelling software